# Django: how to filter a model with ManyToMany relationships

Tags: django, django-models, models

I have a generic ListView where I get some generic stuff (it's not related to my question).

I have model `Product` that has a ManyToMany relationship with `Tag` i.e. a `Product` can have many `Tag` and a `Tag` can be linked to many `Product`.

In this generic ListView, I want to filter all the `Tag` that have actually a `Product` so the customer could click on a `Tag` and I could filter later on.

So far I came to this:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'produits/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'liste_produits'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five created products."""
        return Produit.objects.order_by('-date_v_fin', '-date_v_debut')[:5]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['produits_tags'] = list(
            Tag.objects.values_list('nom', flat=True)
        )
        context['produits_tags'].insert(0, _("Tous"))
        return context
```

But the `Tag.objects.values_list('nom', flat=True)` returns all the `Tag`, including those who have no `Product`. How to filter this?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're after. Do you just want to show all tags that have a product, or do you want to iterate through products and show the tags for each one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to show all tags that have a product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! First of all, make the ManyToMany relationship more readable the other way round by using `related_name` like this:

```
class Produit(BaseModel):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='produits')
```

Then here's how I get all the `Tag` that are used by `Produit`. I guess it's not very optimized, but it works like a charm:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    #blabbla ignoring code in-between
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['produits_tags'] = list(
            Tag.objects.filter(produits__in=Produit.objects.all()).distinct()
        )
        context['produits_tags'].insert(0, _("All"))
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Tag.objects.filter(product_set__isnull=False).values_list('nom', flat=True)
```

Comment: I've tried the opposite way: `Produit.tags.values_list('nom', flat=True)` and I get this error: `'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'values_list'`